# Caching spring 3 hibenrate

Tags: spring, hibernate, caching

I want to know if there is any resource available to explain caching in depth with spring 3 + hibernate(XML annotation based configuration).

I have seen various blog those only give an idea with basic configuration like

- http://eiconsulting.blogspot.in/2011/10/ehcache-implementation-in-spring.html
- http://www.hevi.info/2014/07/maven-3-hibernate-4-spring-3-ehcache-spring-cache/

See this website which explain transactions with spring in detail : http://www.studytrails.com/frameworks/spring/spring-transactions-primer.jsp
So I am looking for similar kind of resource for spring 3 + hibernate with explaining all providers and possible attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching I found following things:
Caching is majorly related to hibernate and spring only works as a glue to facilitates cache providers.

So these are some of the tutorial which are explaining caching with hibernate in detail:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ISi_OkmuQbs&list=PL4AFF701184976B25&index=34
- http://blog.lauramamina.com/article?title=hibernate%20caching%20mechanisms
- This one very is detailed: http://www.javatechtipssharedbygaurav.com/2012/12/hibernate-second-level-ehcache-example.html

And these are some of the help for explaining about how to merge all together (spring + hibernate L2 Ehcache provider)

- https://javattitude.com/2014/05/29/ehcache-configuration-for-spring-4-and-hibernate-4/
- http://eiconsulting.blogspot.in/2011/10/ehcache-implementation-in-spring.html
- https://rahulvishwakarma.wordpress.com/2014/02/23/spring-hibernate-3-2nd-level-ehcache-2-8-configurations-with-c3p0-pooling/

Answer (score 0):

There is very good link with code as below :
https://amitstechblog.wordpress.com/2011/11/08/configuring-ehcache-with-jpa-hibernate-spring/

http://www.theserverside.com/tip/Spring-Ehcache-integration-Second-level-caching-in-Hibernate

It shows the second level caching with ehcache